# Token authentication in django (rest_framework) not working

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

the title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to authenticate with a token. I am getting information from the django database to my flutter app. I've successfully retrieved my token from the rest_framework and added it to the headers of the rest request. I printed these headers in django which results in

```
{
  'Content-Length': '0', 
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
  'User-Agent': 'Dart/2.5 (dart:io)', 
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip', 
  'Authorization': 'Token 10cf58e1402b8e48c1a455aaff7f7bcf53e24231', 
  'Host': '192.168.0.110:8000'
}
```

The result however, is the webpage with a login form and not the rest data that I've requested. What am I missing?

settings.py

```
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    )
}
...
```

views.py

```
...
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def ui_list(request):
    print(request.headers)
    """
    List all code user_informations, or create a new user_information.
    """
    if request.method == "GET":
        users = UserInformation.objects.all()
        serializer = UserInformationSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = UserInformationSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
...
```

Comment: You should receive a 401 unauthorized access, so the issue might be with the url or view, can you show more code ? Does the netry point works with a REST client or documentation ?

Comment: @sebastienbarbier I've added my relevant code of views.py

Comment: I've followed the tutorial from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ with the exception of class-based views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `login_required` is not `rest_framework`s way to authenticate. You need to use permission class for authenticating through your api if that's what you are trying to do.
How I implemented it was, I created a view for login

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    """Class based view loggin in user and returning Auth Token."""

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        """Check if user exists, return token if it does."""
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer_obj = LoginObjectSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer_obj.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=serializer_obj.data['username'], password=serializer_obj.data['password'])
            if not user:
                return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'}, status=404)
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key}, status=200)

        return JsonResponse(serializer_obj.errors, status=400)
```

And how I authenticated my APIs was by using `rest-framework`'s provided permission classes instead of `@login_required`.
My `settings.py` has

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', )
}
```

and the permission class I used to secure my views was like this

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated

authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

But I used like this in class based views. For method based, you can do this as mentioned [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
```

The crux of this is, you are trying to use token based authentication but you are not actually using it. Create your own login api,and use it like mentiond in this answer or the answer of @sebastienbarbier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the use of the decorator `@login_required` which is suppose to protect **a django view**.

Django views and django_rest_framework **do not use the same authentication system** and so need to be implemented differently.

## Manual authentication

You can remove `@login_required` and implement `view.py` as followed :

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
...
@csrf_exempt
def ui_list(request):
    print(request.headers)
    """
    List all code user_informations, or create a new user_information.
    """
    if request.method == "GET":

        user_auth_tuple = TokenAuthentication().authenticate(request)
        if user_auth_tuple is None:
            return HttpResponse(status=401)
        else:
            (user, token) = user_auth_tuple # here come your user object

            users = UserInformation.objects.all()
            serializer = UserInformationSerializer(users, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
         ...
...
```

But doing this process manually is really time consumming, **should not be done this way** as DRSF provide lots of options to make this automatic.

## Class based view

What should actually be done is match a [django rest framework APIView class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) to your model and generate a proper entry point using the permission system.

> **REST framework** provides an **APIView class**, which subclasses Django's View class.
>
> APIView classes are **different** from regular View classes in the following ways:
>
> - Requests passed to the handler methods will be **REST framework's Request** instances, not Django's HttpRequest instances.
> - Handler methods may return REST framework's Response, instead of Django's HttpResponse. The view will manage content negotiation and **setting the correct renderer on the response**.
> - Any APIException exceptions will be caught and mediated into appropriate responses.
> - Incoming requests **will be authenticated and appropriate permission** and/or throttle checks will be run before dispatching the request to the handler method.

Comment: according to the rest_framework documentation, if the authentication headers are set in a http-request, ```request.user``` should contain the relevant user. This would make things a lot easier.

Comment: `@login_required` do not know about DRF http-request so considere your request as unauthentified. rest_framework probably refer to its own Request instance, provided by APIView class ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', ) }
```

adding rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication worked